# How to use Sessions for authentification in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, fetch-api, express-session

I've been trying to make an authentification system with Node.js for a small web app.

So far I've made a login route :

```
app.post('/login', async function(req, res) {
    let login = req.body.login;
    let password = req.body.password;

    let userId = await databaseUsers.verifyUser(login, password);

    if(userId != null) {
        req.session.userId = userId;
    }

    res.send(userId != null);
});
```

Then I created a protected route :

```
app.get('/homepage', requiresLogin, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/homepage.html');
});
```

And a function that checks if the user is logged :

```
function requiresLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.userId) {
        next();
    } 
    else {
        res.send('You must be logged in to view this page.');
    }
}
```

Client-side, i'm using only JS, with the fetch API :

```
let url = "/login";
let headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
});
let init = {    
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    cache: 'default',
    body: JSON.stringify({'login': user.login, 'password': user.password})
};

let verif = await fetch(url, init);
```

Now when I log myself in, the server stores in the session the user's ID.

But when trying to reach */homepage*, i get the 'not connected' error.

I could use a global variable to store the session but therefor multi-user would no longer be an option.

I also thought using cookies, like when the user successfully logs in, the server sends him a cookie.

But then how to handle the user's accesses to the pages ?

Comment: Did you embed express-session in the right way?

Comment: const session = require('express-session'); I used this line, if that's what you mean,

Comment: `I also thought using cookies, like when the user successfully logs in, the server sends him a cookie` thats exactly was express session does :)

Comment: And then? You need to mount it as a middleware ...

Comment: So the current code should send a cookie to the client if I'm correct ?

Comment: app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard'
})); I've set things up this way

Comment: And thats before the other middlewares?

Comment: This is the beggining of my server file : //////////////////
// STATIC FILES //
//////////////////

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/')));

/////////////////
// BODY-PARSER //
/////////////////

app.use(bodyParser.json());

/////////////
// SESSION //
/////////////

app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

Comment: The requiresLogin middlewares is at the end of the file

Comment: And `verif` contains a successvalue?

Comment: It returns the mongoDb ID of the object which I checked is not null

Comment: I just need to ask, the line _req.session.userID_ is enough to send the user a cookie ? If so, I checked in the brower, I don't have any new cookie after getting logged in

Comment: yes it is. express-session reflects the data to the storage automatically. And well you actually found the problem yourself. `fetch` does not store cookies by default :)

Comment: Cheers, It was the problem indeed